# Unexpected Identifier javascript

Tags: javascript, identifier

I have this bit of code that is supposed to output test and then basically do stuff to a div tag. There is some sort of syntax error in it though that outputs" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("test");
    document.getElementById("file").onchange = function(){
        var div = getElementById("imageContainer");
        for each(var image in document.getElementById("file").files){
            div.appendChild("<img src=" + image + "/>");
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: The real cause of the error is for each

Answer (score 3):

**Change:**

```
var div = getElementById("imageContainer");
```

**To:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
```

`getElementById` is a member of the `document` object.

Comment: @DominicOryema You should accept this answer if it solves your problem, notice the check mark to the left right below the voting arrows.